# How can I find unanswered questions with zero answers in some tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, search

I want to find questions within the C++ tag but with zero answers.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for `[c++] answers:0`

Comment: And on the [Search page](http://stackoverflow.com/search) see the "Advanced search tips" for more options like this.

Comment: thanks , how can i find which are not closed in above case

Comment: @user191542 `[c++] answers:0 closed:0`

Comment: How can I find unanswered questions with answers, i.e., there are answer(s) but none has(have) positive score? Tks.

Answer (score 2):

Another way

Go to Unanswered tab tagged c++ and go to *no answeres* tab.

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%2b%2b?tab=noanswers